# analytics make the app crash if no Google Play Services (or gpservices v3)

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services

I implemented Google Analytics v4 with google play service api v6.5 in my android app. At this moment I cannot update the google play service api to the last version (7.5).

The problem is that when a smartphone has no Google account and the Google play services are not up-to-date, the app crash without any error (no logs, no popup in the phone).

Here is the code :

```
GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        analytics.enableAutoActivityReports(this);
        analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
        googleAnalyticsHelper.createTracker(GoogleAnalyticsHelper.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER, R.xml.analytics);
```

and

```
public synchronized Tracker createTracker(TrackerName trackerId, int xmlResId) {
    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(rootContext);
        Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(xmlResId);
        t.set("&tid", ResConfig.getInstance().analyticsTrackingId());
        mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);
    }
    return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
}
```

I need the

```
t.set("&tid", ResConfig.getInstance().analyticsTrackingId());
```

because the tracking id is in my gradle.config, and it depends of my "flavors" in gradle.

I added

```
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"/>
```

as preconized in the doc (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/)

In this doc there is

> Note: Google Analytics can be used and will work on devices that do not have Google Play Services. In this case you still download and use the Google Play Services SDK and Google Analytics will automatically fall back to local dispatching.

but my app crashes 8sec after each launch (without error log neither popup on the smartphone)

Comment: did you find any solution for that?

Comment: Nope, I just deactivate analytics if google play services are not up-to-date... Still waiting for another solution...